# Is it possible to open a file in a window for the user to edit in Python?

Tags: python

I want to have a text file that opens up in a separate window so the user can edit the text inside, and when they close it, the program will read the file. Is this possible?

I have tried googling this, but all I found was how to open a .py file or how to use the open() function to have the program automatically edit files.

Comment: in a separate window from what? you could have a python script running as a service that constantly monitors the modification date of a file, so when a user opens, modifies and saves the file a script can be triggered that will read the file

Comment: Which is the operating system you are going to use?

Comment: You can e. g. run a text editor with "os.system" or "subprocess.run".

Answer (score 1):

Well, what you can do is the following, using `supprocess`

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["code", "/your/file/full-path/example.txt", "--wait"])

# This will be executed once the program terminates,
# so when the user closes the window (or the tab, in this case,
# since we are using  VS Code)

print("done")
```

In this example, I used VS Code, `code` command, with the `--wait` parameter; if you are on a Windows operating system you may replace `code` with `notepad` (or any text editor) and remove the `--wait`.

Note that the `print()` is executed once the program is closed. In your case, after the `subprocess.call()` execution is finished, your file have been updated (unless the user decided to not saving the file).

You can find other examples here: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/python-run-external-command-and-get-output/

**Edit**

As suggested by @Robert in the comments, it is also possible to use `open` (Mac) or `xdg-open` (Linux) commands to open your file with the default system-defined application, depending on your file extension.

Comment: Instead of hard-coding the application, you could use `open` on Mac and `xdg-open` on Linux (at least with xfce4). There may or may not be something similar for Windows.

Comment: Yes, that makes lot of sense but not sure if the question is assuming that we want to open a specific application, I think `open` starts the system defined one, according to the default application defined for a given file extension, right?

Comment: Yes, it does, and wouldn't that be what the user expects?

Comment: Let me add this option in the answer too.

Comment: Probably not worth adding it, the question is closed, I already upvoted your answer, and it's already here in the comments. ;-)

Comment: Lol, I started the editing before the answer was closed hahahah I think the question was OK btw, it was clear and useful imo

Comment: It was clear, but it showed total lack of research and effort invested by the OP, who just claimed to not have found anything.